# How to pass an object of type as a parameter to Web Api Get/Post method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-web-api, routes

Here is my Post method and i am passing an object which contains parameters

```
public class TransactionController : ApiController
{
 [HttpPost]
    public TransactionResponse mytest2(TransactionOperationInput input)
    {
       // some operation here 
    }
}
```

Here is the URL i am trying to test

```
http://localhost:33755/api/Transaction/mytest2?SourceKey=abcdef&Pin=123&Criteria=2018-09-12 00:00:00
```

**Outcome When method is set to POST and Get**

[HttpPost] : I get an error 405 method not allowed.

[HttpGet] : input parameter is NULL

This is the Register Route class; ( sorry i am new to Route tables)

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Do i need to update route table? or Is my URL wrong?

Also, should i have the service method as Post or Get?

Comment: You cannot navigate to a POST method (it needs to be a `[HttpGet]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot navigate to a `[HttpPost]` method, so it needs to be a `[HttpGet]`. And to bind to a complex object from query string values, you need to use the `[FromUri]` attribute

```
[HttpGet] // can be omitted 
public TransactionResponse mytest2([FromUri]TransactionOperationInput input)
```

For more information on parameter binding in web-api, refer [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api).